# Java 2D array copy

Tags: java

I have a 2D array and I just need to copy the first row into another array of the same size. What is the best way of doing this? I tried this:

```
public static int[][] buildCME(int[][] array){

    int [][] arrayCME = new int[array.length][array[0].length];


    for(int y = 1; y < array.length; y++)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
        {

            arrayCME[y][x] = array[y][x];

        }
    }
```

However that is just giving me 0's for the first row, which I assume has to do with my int initialization. I created this for loop because I thought it would be easier to account for than to create an if statement in a normal for loop to account for the whole 2D array. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your outer loop begins on 1, not 0 and as arrays start at 0, the first row will always be unchanged.

Comment: That's what I want to happen, for it to not be changed, but when I print out arrayCME it's all 0's for the first row

Comment: What @Aaron means is that the first row of arrayCME will be unchanged from the default -- which is all zeroes -- which is not what you want.  Make the outer loop start at 0.

Answer (score 5):

Your code copies the first column (your inner loop is x < 1) starting from the second row (outer loop starts at 1). If you want to copy the first row do

```
 for (int x = 0; x < array[0].length; x++)
 {
      arrayCME[0][x] = array[0][x];
 }
```

To do this more efficiently, you might want to have a look at [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
System.arraycopy(array[0],0,arrayCME[0],0,array[0].length);
```

`System.arraycopy` should perform a more efficient copy since it is a [native](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) method. Furthermore, some JVMs like for example the HotSpot JVM treat this method as an *intrinsic*. A JVM will usually substitute calls to intrinsics methods with architecture specific code, which in the case of `arraycopy` might be machine code that copies memory directly.